# Reccuring payments ambiguity

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have a class for recurring payments for subscriptions and there is a thing that is not 100% clear for me.
If I initialize an order with following params:

```
Amount: 25$
Initial amount: 0
Period: month
Freq: 3
```

Does this mean that the user is paying 25$ three months from now or does he pay 25 now with no extra charge (initial amount)?
In other words, what I am asking is - is the initial payment some extra charge or can it be used as a advanced payments for the first cycle subscription, in which case, the params I would need would be:

```
Amount: 25$
Initial amount: 25$
Period: month
Freq: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the initial amount is requested immediately, the reoccurring amount is taken depending on the billing cycle and the start date

[this guide might help explain](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/)
If the initial amount request fails then the default is to not activate the reoccurring payments.